# How do I pass values from a ruby back-end to a jquery confirmation dialog?

Tags: jquery, ruby, sinatra

I'm building a web application with a Ruby back-end (Mostly Sinatra, Not Rails). The application is to manage Institutions, People and their subscriptions.

I wanted to have custom confirmation dialog boxes when a user deletes something. For example:

If a user deletes an institution named "Company A", I want to say: `Are you sure you want to delete Company A`

If they delete a person named "John Doe", I want to say: `Are you sure you want to delete John Doe?`

If they delete a subscription, called "Subscription A", from John Doe, I want to say: `Are you sure you want to delete Subscription A from John Doe`

I currently have a jQuery-based delete confirmation dialog that looks like this:

```
$('a.delete-action').click(function(event) {

    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?")) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
});
```

The associated HTML and ERB are:

```
<p><a class="action-link delete-action" href="/institutions/<%= @institution.id %>/remove">Remove <%= @institution.name %></a></p>
```

How do I pass in the name of the institution/person/subscription/all of those things to the jQuery dialog?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the name as an attribute on the link

```
<a href='...' data-name='John Doe'>...</a>
```

Then extract the attribute in your click handler

```
$('a.delete-action').click(function(event) {
  var name = $(this).data('name')
  var prompt = "Are you sure you want to delete " + name + "?"

  if (confirm(prompt)) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
});
```

Comment: How secure would that be? Just to note, the site is secured through SSL and it can't be accessed without logging in. But just to cover my bases, what kind of risks would I be exposing myself to if I put this (rather sensitive) data directly in a link? And would it be possible using an AJAX call (with an id to look up in the database)? Or would that be overkill?

Comment: @UmarGhouse What do you mean "sensitive"? You're serving it on the page anyway. It is not in any way more "exposed" in this way than in yours.

Comment: Right. I didn't think of that. I feel stupid now. Thanks @Sergio Tulentsev I'll try this out! One more question though, just for learning purposes. About using AJAX instead. Would that be a viable alternative?

Comment: @UmarGhouse it'd be an unnecessary complication :) What would you hope to accomplish with that (what you can't do now)?

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right. Just started working with AJAX, still haven't worked off that need to use it for everything yet! :P Thanks again @Sergio Tulentsev , this solution worked like a charm!